# 100% height doesn't work on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Check live- http://uposonghar.com/testsite/

When i add more items to the menus - the menu container does not expand and items get outside the menu.

Screenshot-
[image]

Code-

```
<LI id=navPreretire><A title="Pre Retirement Procedures"  href="http://pencproc/" target=_blank><SPAN class=singleLine>Pre Retirement Procedures</SPAN> </A>

        <!--Mega menu drop-down part1, the div have to stay like that-->
        <div class="dropdown">
        <!--until here-->
            <Ul>
                <div class="dropdown_3rd_lvl1"><li ><a href="#">Plan Benifit Payment Procedures</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Manage Payments</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Manage Pension Benefits</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    </UL></li></div>

                <div class="dropdown_3rd_lvl2"><li ><a href="#">Pension Services Procedures</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Manage Group Benefits</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Manage Payments</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Manage Pension Benefits</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    </UL></li></div>

            </ul>
       <!--Menu ends-->
       </div>
       <!--Menu ends-->
    </LI>
```

CSS-

```
.dropdown{
display: none;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #886d53;
clear: both; 
}

.dropdown>ul>li{
clear: both;   
float: left;    
}

#menu li:hover .dropdown{
position: absolute;
display: block;
height:100%;
min-width: 430px;
margin: 38px auto; 
padding-top: 5px;    
}

.dropdown ul li{
clear: both;    
}

#menu .dropdown ul li:hover{
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: In fact it does but I think you have a z-index problem.

Comment: I already add z-index but no luck.

Comment: Your html/css are not well organized. Everywhere you used unnecessary `div`s, `height`, `absolute` position!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove unnecessary `height`, `position:absolute`.

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown {
    /*height: 200px;*/
}
#menu ul ul {
    height: auto;
}
.dropdown_3rd_lvl1 {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*left: 0*/
    /*margin-left: -30px;*/
    float: left;
}
.dropdown_3rd_lvl2 {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*margin-left: 170px;*/
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, at least partly, due to your `#menu ul`, which applies a `height: 38px` to the bar, but also gets applied to the `ul` descendant a few layers deeper.

The entire menu bar seems a bit too complex for what you are trying to achieve, and could be done in a much simpler way.

Comment: Problem is in dropdown, when i add fix height(like height:300px) that is working, but not working when i add height:100%

Comment: Could you isolate and recreate the issue with some cleaner code on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Also, height 100% isn't working because it is calculating 100% based off its parent, which is 38px. If you don't declare a height, all of the ul children (who are being affected by your #menu ul) are determining a height of 38px.